# Map<String, dynamic> for FireStore Errors

Tags: angular, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, angular-dart

Trying to create a Map for items from FireStore as such:

```
class Hero {
  final int id;
  String name;
  bool pickupNeeded;
  String url;
  bool partPickup;


  Hero(this.id, this.name, this.pickupNeeded, this.url, this.partPickup);


  factory Hero.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> hero) =>
      Hero(_toInt(hero['id']), hero['name'], hero['pickupNeeded'], hero['url'], hero['partPickup']);

  Map toJson() => {'id' : id, 'name': name, 'pickupNeeded' : pickupNeeded, 'url' : url, 'partPickup' : partPickup,};

  int _toInt(id) => id is int ? id : int.parse(id);
```

However, the `_toInt in the hero(_toInt(hero['id']`... give the error: "Instance members can't be accessed from a factory constructor"

What am I missing? The AngularDart Tour of Heroes has is like this on their [`GitHub sample`](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-6/blob/master/lib/src/hero.dart).

**hero_service get Hero Call:**

```
Future<Hero> get(dynamic id) async {
    try {
      return Hero.fromJson(id);
    } catch (e) {
      throw _handleError(e);
    }
  }
```

**And the Hero Component that is calling it:**

```
void onActivate(_, RouterState current) async {
    final id = RoutePaths().getId(current.parameters);
    if (id != null) hero = await (_heroService.get(id));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `_toInt` static and you're golden.

```
static int _toInt(id) => id is int ? id : int.parse(id);
```

Comment: Maybe not. That gets rid of the Dart Analyzer error, but when I try to run it, I get an error: Type 'int' is not a subtype of expected type 'Map<String, dynamic>'   No matter what type I try changing it to, I get a similar error.

Comment: Type 'int' is not a subtype of expected type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
    EXCEPTION: Exception: Server error; cause: Type 'int' is not a subtype of 
    expected type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
    STACKTRACE: 
    dart:sdk_internal

Comment: Are you trying to call `Hero.fromJson(..)` w/ an int value?

Comment: Yes. I believe the RoutePaths returns an int. I have added the items making the calls. HeroComponent calls HeroService. Note: when i forced the int id to a String, I got the same error.